# What should my Redirect URI be for a webapi between website and mobile application

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a webapi plugin for my ecommerce site that uses Oauth 2

```
client id : "automatically generated"
client secret : "Automatically generated"
Callback Uri:     This is blank  <----- What should this be?
```

For example if my website is https://www.mywebsite.com what should the Callback URI be?

I will create two clients in this api. One for webaccess for testing and another for IOS development.
I just need to know what should the callback URI be in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be anything. For instance `https://www.mywebsite.com/my/callback/resource`, but you can have more than one also if you like. Here’s the flow, your uri(s) will handle B D and F. See the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
[image: oauth2-flow]

Edit: here's what the specification says about the callback url:

> Redirection endpoint - used by the authorization server to return
> responses containing authorization credentials to the client via
> the resource owner user-agent.

> The redirection endpoint URI MUST be an absolute URI as defined by
> [RFC3986] Section 4.3.  The endpoint URI MAY include an
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" formatted (per Appendix B) query
> component ([RFC3986] Section 3.4), which MUST be retained when adding
> additional query parameters.  The endpoint URI MUST NOT include a
> fragment component.

So *aside from fragmentation*, the url can be w/e you like

Comment: So what confuses me is https://www.mywebsite.com/my/callback/resource doesnt exist as an actual webpage. Does that not matter? So basically it could be https://www.mywebsite.com/foo/bar?

Comment: That's my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This url might throw some light on your requirement.

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uris-native-apps/

It says to use myapp:// so that it can redirect with authorization code to your app.